# Lity scrolls up

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm using [Lity](http://sorgalla.com/lity/) and I'm sort of having a problem understanding how to use it.

I tried this:

```
<a href="#storythree" data-lity>Read More</a>
<div id="storythree" style="background:#fff" class="lity-hide">
<h1> ****'s story </h1>
<p> lorem ipsum... </p>
```

But whenever I click "read more", the window opens up but, the screen is scrolled all the way up. And when I close the window is goes back to the page from where it is. I have the Jquery and the other files uploaded too.

Comment: what you want to do explain briefly

Comment: I have this lity that I'm using, it's a modal. Whenever I click the button to open the modal, it scrolls up. [link]( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZA4npi-mJI&feature=youtu.be) here is a screen grab.